# Excluding Appendix Chapters in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I was wondering if there is any way to exclude the individual Chapters within the Appendix so that the TOC only shows one line labeled as "appendices"?

I am using the begin{appendices} as I want it to be sectioned off from my main document. I also tried using \chapter* but I want to keep the Appendix A label above the title of the appendix.

```
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\begin{appendices}

\chapter{sometext}

\chapter{somemoretext}

\end{appendices}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{appendices}

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}% Insert reference to Appendices in ToC
\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}% Remove ability to add content to ToC

\chapter{sometext}

\chapter{somemoretext}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

The idea would be to add **Appendices** to the ToC manually at the start of the `appendices` environment (either in the text, or within the preamble) and also remove the capability of adding additional content by making `\addcontentsline` a no-op. It will gobble its three arguments and do nothing.